# I can't ping windows azure VM's VIP from my local machine

Tags: windows, azure, hadoop, azure-virtual-machine, hadoop-partitioning

I have created Windows azure VM and also installed HADOOP in it. Now I want to access HDFS by using URL from my local machine so that i can perform read and write operation. Please guide me the steps to perform this task. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you configured the firewall appropriately to open necessary ports?

Comment: Yes, ran  this command to enable ICMPv4 --> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" dir=in action=allow enable=yes protocol=icmpv4:8,any

Comment: I can able to to RDP but not able to ping VIP and also not able  to do SSH connection. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Pinging is disabled on Azure VM. That could be the reason for not being able to ping.

Comment: I enabled ping by running this command on Azure VM --> "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" dir=in action=allow enable=yes protocol=icmpv4:8,any" .

Comment: is their anything else I need to check ?

Answer (score 1):

As @GauravMantri has mentioned in the comment, Azure disable the ICMP for security reasons.

To verify if a service running on azure VM is reachable, please use a port detector. On Windows platform, we can use the [Port Query](https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=24009). If you are using Linux, then please try nmap.

BTW, if you can  ping a machine, it only means that you have a routable path to the destination computer and its TCP/IP stack works. The port detector is more accurate when you try to check if a service is reachable from the client.

> Now I want to access HDFS by using URL from my local machine so that i can perform read and write operation.

If you are using Azure Classic VM, then you should configure the [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json) to allow the access to HADOOP service.

If you are using the Azure Resource Manager VM, then you should configure the inbound rules of [NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal) to allow the access to HADOOP service.